# Magento 2: How to upload a banner slider on magento homepage?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, home-page, banner-slider

I have created the banner slider using HTML ,CSS and JS it has nothing related to magento but is a simple banner slider how do i put it on my magento homepage? Or How do i convert it to an magento extension?